# How to randomise carpet texture to make it more 'real'

Tags: uv, text-object

I have imported a carpet texture onto a plane, however the particles of the carpet look extremely large in relation to the stool:

[image]

I have tried to scale it down, however the carpet looks 'repeated' and unnatural:
[image]

How do I randomise my carpet to make it look more real? Or is there a better technique for implementing carpet in my scene?

Comment: This addon could help you:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xNnuZjD9bK0